# Firefox 28 (only Win7) crash after JS memory leak

Tags: javascript, firefox, memory-leaks

I'm fighting whole day trying to find cause of strange memory leak, which only exist in Firefox 28 and only on Windows 7 - Chrome (Linux / Win 7) is fine, as well as that same version of Firefox for Linux. It's also fine on older version of Firefox for Windows.

It's even more bizarre because that same functionality is working fine for FF 28 / Win 7 with three different data-sets, but for other two it's leaking and crashing browser... And everything is completely fine for all five sets on other platforms / browsers...

Have somebody idea what's going on? Or could help me get some proper tracking tools or maybe know some bug reports for similar issues on Mozilla page?

And I'm sure that this is not caused by add-ons - I've installed fresh copy of Firefox and even run with safe mode on - it's still crashing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've found what causing memory leak in my case. Maybe this will help others with similar issue:**

---

This problem was caused (probably) by this bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=972515

I have some charts on my page and few of them are a spark-line. I was using this code for animations ([source](http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326)):

```
var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
  .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

In some cases `path.node().getTotalLength();` was returning `NaN` and cause memory leak while animating. Removing above code from my charts fix the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I’ve just been FED UP with FF because of all of the memory leaks, etc. I've been running v16 forever because whenever I’ve tried to upgrade to newer versions, they’d all pretty much just crash after 30 minutes of heavy use, and not a single version of FF that I’ve ever used has ever fixed the memory leak problems. Not a single one.

I actually installed a tiny batch file on quicklaunch so I could quickly kill FF at the point it’s consumed all of my RAM so I could then start over with “Restore Session” to automatically reload all of my previous tabs. After trying every “solution” to the leak problem, that’s the only one that ever did me any good. Apparently the arrogant tards at mozilla would rather tweak the UI to death rather than make a browser that actually works. They’re worse than even Microsoft because Microsoft has to listen to their customers sooner or later or go broke, whereas nonprofits can just drift along forever.

At any rate, I just finished installing PM, including importing everything from FF with their little importer program, and everything went flawlessly, including all settings and the plethora of add-ons I use. The only difficulty was getting roboform attached, which I can’t live without. I did finally dumb around and got the roboform taskbar program to attach roboform to PM, which then worked flawlessly. It is, however, necessary for the roboform taskbar program to run all the time for roboform to continue to work on PM, but this is a very small price to pay to ditch FF forever.

I've used PM for a week now, opening/closing/keeping hundreds of tabs a day, and I’ve been stunned at how much faster PM is than FF, as well as the VERY small memory footprint occupied by PM vs FF. Even after a week's HEAVY usage, PM has not grown beyond 1 GB, and even better, when I close tabs, ALL of the RAM is given back.

Basically, PM is what FF ought to be. Even better, the genius behind Pale Moon, Mark Straver, has committed to keeping the PM UI fundamentally unmolested. I’ll be installing PM instead of FF on all of my client’s computers in the future as well!

(BTW, ALL of the "recommended fixes" for the firefox memory leak problems are a sick joke. Not one of them works. And plugins DO NOT cause the memory leaks! Firefox does! How do I know? Because I switched to Pale Moon, importing everything EXACTLY like it was in Firefox and guess what? No memory leaks in Pale Moon! Oh, and I use Adblock Plus, Flash, Java, DoNotTrackMe, BetterPrivacy CookieCuller, DownloadHelper, Element Hiding Helper, IE View, ViewAbout, Visited, and roboform. So NONE of those is causing the firefox memory leak problems!)